# Bootstrap: Make glyph diagram scale with screen size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scaling

I'm designing a diagram (for lack of a better word), made up of shapes and glyphs, and I would like it to change size with screen size.  I've done my best to recreate this is a fiddle (Seen below).  When you change the size of the screen, some circles overflow into the next line, when I'd like the entire diagram to scale down (almost like in a fluid container).

https://jsfiddle.net/qE9kJ/185/

```
<div class="glyphicon-belt">
    <div id="rectangle"></div>

    <div class="container circle-container circle-1">
        <i class="icon-star" style="font-size: 60px"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="container circle-container circle-2">
        <i class="icon-envelope" style="font-size: 60px"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="container circle-container circle-3">
        <i class="icon-smile" style="font-size: 60px"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: set the font-size based on window width and height using javascript

Comment: I got it working, but the third circle still wraps to the following line when I decrease the width too much.  Any thoughts why that might be happening?

Comment: **I got it working.** can you provide the working fiddle .

Comment: something along these lines https://jsfiddle.net/qE9kJ/189/

Comment: remove this `.circle-1 {    margin-right: 17%;}` from styles and add margin-right as inline style like you added  height,width in the fiddle in comments.